# Arabic Vowels not appearing

Tags: fonts, accents, ligatures, arabic

I'm trying to write this word with the circled vowels but I'm not being able to, can someone help?

[image]

When I'm writing with the vowels, it is becomming like الله

An example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % this package is for creating filler text
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{utf8}
\author{N.~N}
\title{The booklet}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى
\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is very difficult with LaTeX with some packages like TiKz or pstricks. Do you know Kelk: http://sinasoft.com/Kelk.htm

Comment: nopes, I don't know

Comment: Please post an MWE (minimum working example -- a LaTeX program that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` -- that gives rise to the problem behavior. Without knowing what exactly you've done so far, it's really tricky to provide a diagnosis of the situation, let alone suggest a solution.

Comment: Which font are you using? As far as I know this depends a lot on the font which is supposed to render the correct ligature "itself" once you've simply typed ʾalif+lām+lām+hāʾ without any vowels or additional signs: `ا + ل + ل + ه = الله`. You could also try to use the single Unicode character FDF2 `ﷲ` which, however, is not recommended nowadays.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in providing a working example

Comment: You should consider switching from `arabtex` to `arabxetex`, with which you can use any OpenType or TrueType font on your system. I just tried your example with Scheherazade, Lateef, Amiri, and IranNastaliq; the latter comes closest to the font in your image, though it’s not the same font.

Comment: by the way: what do you mean by "When i'm writing with the vowels, it is becomming like الله"? -- isn't الله what you want?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure that I understand your question; is it the exact form of the vowel mark in the name of God that concerns you?

If so, see pp. 21 and 27 of arabdoc.pdf for getting the “dagger alif” in `arabtex`.  I don’t know whether you can get it in `arabtex` without using the ASCII input notation.

In `arabxetex`, you can get it, at least in some readily available fonts, by typing the unicode character `FDF2` directly, as ClintEastwood suggested: see the second line of my example. You can also get it by letting a well designed font handle the ligature, as in the third line of the example below. The first line, from your example, seems to break the font’s automatic recognition of the ligature by explicit input of the *shadda*.

```
% must be compiled with xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
\author{N.\,N.}
\title{The booklet}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{arab}
اللَّهِ

\bigskip

ﷲ

\bigskip

اللهِ
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the example]

There are many more details about this particular ligature in section 3.3.1 of the documentation for `arabxetex`, including comments about the behavior of various fonts.

Comment: You might add `اللهِ` as a third line to your example because this is -- I think -- what the Noor wants (if I understood him correctly).

Comment: Thanks, @ClintEastwood, I’ve incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: `FDF2` should be avoided, it is a compatibility character and should not be used in new data. Most Arabic fonts will put the shadda and dagger alef on `الله` by default anyway (Amiri trays to be smart here and only put them only if there is no explicit shadda).